# Unresolved reference: embedding and Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity in MainActivity.kt

Tags: android, flutter

My flutter app was working fine until days I go when it stopped building successfully

**android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/apps/myapp/MainActivity.kt** file

```
package com.apps.myapp

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
 
}
```

**Console**

```
Built build/app/outputs/repo.
Building plugin workmanager...
✓ Built build/app/outputs/repo.
e: /home/apps/myapp/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/apps/myapp/MainActivity.kt: (3, 19): Unresolved reference: embedding
e: /home/apps/myapp/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/apps/myapp/MainActivity.kt: (5, 21): Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Help in fixing this issue please! thank you.

Comment: did you try to run 'gradlew clean' in your android project before building it again ?

Comment: Yes.. Multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution on this. In my case the problems were being caused by `location: ^1.4.1` package. I solved this issue by using an alternative package which is `geolocator: ^5.1.1`. I hope this helps someone too, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're on at least flutter 2.2.2. i had the same problem but i was able to fix it by:

1. updating all my flutter plugins in `pubspec.yaml`
2. updating flutter to 2.2.2
3. try and avoid using plugins on the native sides (if not needed)
4. compileSdkVersion 30 and  targetSdkVersion 30
5. ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
6. classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
7. android.enableR8=true in your android/gradle.properties